# How to solve a problem from Frank Olver's book

Tags: cv.complex-variables, asymptotics

I'm learning **Frank Olver**'s book, called **Asymptotics and Special Functions**. There is an difficult exercise.

> **Problem.** Suppose that $f,\frac{1}{f}$ possess the following asymptotic expansions :
>   $$f(z)\sim \sum_{s=0}^{\infty}f_s z^{-s},\frac{1}{f(z)}\sim \sum_{s=0}^{\infty}k_s z^{-s}$$
>   as $z\to \infty$ in the region **F**, contained in $\mathbb{C}$. That is to say
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)& =\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}f_s z^{-s}+\phi_n(z),\\
> \frac{1}{f(z)}& =\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}k_s z^{-s}+\psi_n(z),
> \end{align*}
>   where $\left|\phi_n(z)\right|\leqslant K_n\left|z\right|^{-n},\left|\psi_n(z)\right|\leqslant L_n\left|z\right|^{-n}$, and $K_n,L_n$ are the least constants satisfying last two inequalities. Show that
>   $$L_n\leqslant \frac{1}{m}\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}|k_s|K_{n-s},\ n\geqslant 1,$$
>   where $m=\inf_{z\in \mathbf{F}}|f(z)|$.

I have got the recurrence relation :
$$f_0 k_s=-\left(f_1 k_{s-1}+f_2 k_{s-2}+\cdots+f_s k_0\right)$$
for $s=1,2,\cdots$. For example,
$$k_0=\frac{1}{f_0},k_1=-\frac{f_1}{f_0^2},k_2=\frac{f_1^2-f_0 f_2}{f_0^3}.$$
But I absolutely have no idea to prove the origin problem.